# Masking ASP.NET TextBox as password when TextMode is MultiLine

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET `TextBox` with `TextMode` set to as `MultiLine`. The content of the `TextBox` should be displayed as password instead of plain text.

At same time it is not possible to set `TextMode` as both `Password` and `MultiLine`. Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: OnPaint is windows form method. I want a solution related web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a non-trivial way to achieve this without finding a low level solution.

- When you set `TextBox.TextMode` as `Password` then an `<input type="password"/>`
- When you set `TextBox.TextMode` as `MultiLine` then a `<textarea/>`

HTML element is rendered to the client.

The problem is that the `TextArea` HTML element doesn't support password characters. But there is a reasonable workaround: *Using CSS style to blur* the `TextBox` characters. First add a new item (Web Forms Server Control) to your project and modify it so that it looks like:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestAspNetWebApp
{
    [DefaultProperty("Text")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:SecretTextArea runat=server></{0}:SecretTextArea>")]
    public class SecretTextArea : TextBox
    {
        public SecretTextArea()
        {
            TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
            Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "transparent");
            Attributes.CssStyle.Add("text-shadow", "0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)");

            Text = "This is a semi-secret text.";
        }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            output.Write(Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Build your project. Drag-n-drop the `SecretTextArea` control from VS Toolbox to your web form. The result is:

[image]

The advantage of this blurring method is that you can see and edit the text. Also you can set the blurring amount by changing the `px` value in the `text-shadow` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have to "compromise" somewhat here.

So, when the user types, you not see "*", but they will not see what they type.

So, drop in a text box, set mode = "multi-line", and thus this markup:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"
            style="color: transparent;text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);"
            Height="213px" Width="307px"                               
            ></asp:TextBox>
```

So, we add a blur to the text, and the result is actually quite nice:

eg this:

[image]

If you don't compromise a bit, then you can find some "messy" JavaScript solutions. However, I think the above works and looks just as well/nice as a password box with "*" anyway.

And such a text box? Well, I have no idea why one wants this (perhaps a screen to send some secret message).

So, try the above, I think it is a "reasonable" solution.